# Помогите, пожалуйста, возможно ли это реализовать? C++

Tags: c++

Я пишу свой класс строк. В самом начале я решил, что должно быть в этом классе:

1. Класс занимает ровно столько байтов, сколько символов хранит в себе
2. Он не должен быть медленнее string
3. Он работает с бинарными и обычными строками

То зачем я суда обратился: Мне нужно реализовать 3 пункт. И проблема заключается в том, что я не могу определить точный размер массива который будет хранить мой класс, следовательно и не могу скопировать его в внутренний буфер своего класса. Что я могу сделать для этого и возможно ли это вообще???

Comment: Размер бинарной строки для хранения должен задаваться из вне. Условие 1 является невыполнимым, так как класс еще должен хранить длину строки.

Comment: @user7860670 Или строка из 5 символов и строка из 8 символов — просто разные *типы* строк :)

Comment: Длину можно не хранить, а использовать _msize(И ссылку на внутренний буфер класса)

Comment: `_msize` не является стандартной функцией, и работает только с блоками, выделенными через Сшный malloc. Ну и все равно выходит, что размер будет храниться.

Comment: @HarryfromKiev Тогда это по сути `::std::array<char`. Мне представляется, что более толковый подход был бы сделать что-то вроде pascal string, с хранением размера в буфере перед байтами строки.

Comment: @user7860670 А если строка еще и может изменяться — то ее надо еще и динамически выделять, еще и указатель...

Comment: @HarryfromKiev Строка действительно должна выделяться динамически, однако указателей хранится не должно.

Answer (score 2):

1. Думаю, нереально. Разве что только если строка известна заранее и в процессе работы не изменяется (по крайней мере не изменяется ее размер), тогда шаблоны такое позволят.
2. Ну, дело умения :) Но зависит от того, *что именно* этот класс должен уметь! Потому что ограничения из п.1 не дадут реализовать ряд функциональности.
3. А в чем вообще разница между бинарными и текстовыми строками? Что это такое — бинарная строка? Текстовая строка?

Comment: Концом текстовой строки будет нуль терминатор, а в бинарной - нет (Так как она может содержать любые символы ascii)

Comment: Тогда точно надо хранить размер, как минимум, для бинарной строки

Comment: Наличие нуль-терминатора нарушает правило — это лишний байт... :)

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, вы в Киеве или уехали?

Comment: @avp Логичный вопрос... Надо бы переименоваться в *Harry in Kiev*, но это только раз в месяц можно...

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, держитесь, удачи вам.

Comment: @avp Спасибо. Работа отвлекает... Если что — всем советую, сразу на взрывы реагируешь спокойнее :)

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, да уж... Никогда такого не мог представить

Comment: @avp Да уж, армейские приколы "пишу письмо на броне горящего танка" — фигня по сравнению "пишу программу под "Градами"..." :)

Comment: @Harry from Kiev, а по мне это тоже фигня по сравнению с тем, что еще будет в мире....