# Почему я не могу поймать это исключение??? C++

Tags: c++

Долго я искал способ узнать точное количество char-ов в массиве (Как тот что находиться в стеке, так и тот, что находиться в куче) И вот я нарыл способ определить размер массива который находиться в стеке и способ для динамического (_msize() и sizeof()), казалось бы - надо всего сделать это:

```
size_t getsize(char* memblock)
{
    try
    {
        return _msize(memblock);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return sizeof(memblock);
    }
}
```

Но нет, исключение которое бросает _msize() попросту не хочет обрабатываться и прога просто завершается, что с этим можно сделать???

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1393601/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-c#comment2476803_1393601

Comment: И эта функция не бросает исключений, так как это С. И эта функция не определяет размер массива, она возвращает размер выделенного блока памяти. Размер массива у указателю определить невозможно.

Comment: Но программа все равно завершается, как этого избежать и обработать???? @user7860670

Comment: Очевидно, что в эту функцию нельзя передавать абы какой указатель. В противном случае возникает неопределенное поведение.